# Vim-like terminal email client?

Tags: vim, email, software-rec

Looking foward to vim-like email clients (TUI or GUI).

For example:

- `5dd` should delete the next 5 email messages starting from the cursor.
- `/bar` should search for "bar" in email titles and messages.
- `'` should go to bookmarked messages
- `m` should bookmark messages
- `:` should enter command mode

If those keybindings aren't predefined, there should be a way to define custom
keybindings to do the job. Also, it should be possible to define external editor
to send emails.

Does anyone know of some software that satisfies that?

(Just saying, I've tried neomutt but I've been unable to do some things like
`5dd` or `'`. I don't know if that is actually possible, so I decided to ask
here in any case).

Comment: mutt/neomutt is probably the closest to what you want, but the keybindings will be different (you can customise them in your .muttrc, but i'm not sure if you can do things like 5dd).  You can certainly edit messages in vim (I do that, and I have `set edit_headers` enabled so I can edit headers in vim too).   mutt doesn't have "bookmarking", but you can tag messages individually or with various search types (to/from, other headers, body, dates, msg number ranges, and more), and limit the display to only tagged messages.

Comment: To delete a range of messages, say from msg 20 to msg 25 you could tag and delete them with `T~m20-25<enter>;d`.  You *may* be able to write some kind of macro to automate that (perhaps even from current line to current line +5), but I've never tried to do that so don't know for sure.

Comment: Thank you @cas . Where can I learn more about that ? A couple of months ago I was lazy and configured mutt with mutt-wizard, but now I'm trying to customize it myself and I'm a bit lost because there are so much things.

Comment: See `man muttrc`, the [mutt manual](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/) (which may be installed on your system - e.g. if you're running Debian, look in `/usr/share/doc/mutt/`, there should be `manual.txt.gz` and a `html/` sub-directory, as well as an `examples/` sub-directory), and the rest of the [mutt.org](http://www.mutt.org/) web site.    Or neomutt's documentation, if you're using that.

Comment: this is probably more suitable for [softwarerecs.se]

Answer (score 0):

`mutt` mail client is highly configurable. You will not get `5dd` as in `vim`, but you can map most of the other commands you mention.